# Flask SqlAlchemy : Records not displayed

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my code :

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Restaurant, MenuItem

app = Flask(__name__)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/')
def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id):
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id=restaurant.id)
    output = ''
    for i in items:
        output += i.name
        output += '</br>'
        output += i.price
        output += '</br>'
        output += i.description
        output += '</br>'
        output += '</br>'
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I run the file by entering the following URL :

```
localhost:5000/restaurants/2
```

And all I get is a blank page. I don't get any kind of error in my GitBash or browser or anywhere else.

I ran this simple code :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/hello')
def HelloWorld():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

And this runs perfectly. What wrong am I doing ?

**EDIT : 1**

Tried to debug the code and noticed that the code doesn't enter the `for i in items:` loop.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/hello')
def restaurantMenu():
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).first()
    items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id = restaurant.id)
    output = ''
    print restaurant.name
    print restaurant.id

    if not items :
        print "No menu items!"
    else:
        print "There are menu items!"
        for i in items:
            print "In items loop!"
            output += i.name
            output += '<br>'
    return output + "Hello"
```

[image]

Comment: Have you setup your database so that there are actually records returned? As your code is written, an empty response is a perfectly valid response if no records are retrieved.

Comment: I have records in the database! Is there someway to debug ?

Comment: @sholsapp : Please see the screen capture i have added of the gitbash.. for what am i getting a 404 ?

Comment: ignore that 404 its just a favicon icon

Comment: @Ja8zyjits : Just realised!

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh to debug put an intentional error in restaurantMenu like a `raise` and it will show an error in the browser, since you have debug set to true.
from there query your tables and debug

Comment: @Ja8zyjits : Trying that now!

Comment: @Ja8zyjits : http://pastebin.com/XDh8xNpG Please see this. The code reaches the `else` block but does not enter the `for` loop! Why so ? See the update question for code and screenshot of gitbash

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh `print "There are menu items!",items` put this in the else block and tell me whats the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102059/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-ja8zyjits).

Comment: @Ja8zyjits : I get this message : `There are menu items! SELECT menu_item.name AS menu_item_name, menu_item.id AS menu_item_id, menu_item.description AS menu_item_description, menu_item.price AS menu_item_price, menu_item.course AS menu_item_course, menu_item.restaurant_id AS menu_item_restaurant_id 
FROM menu_item 
WHERE menu_item.restaurant_id = ?`

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh `items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id = restaurant.id).all()`, this will fix it.
Basically you are only querying but not getting the results, you used `.first()` for restaurants but you dint use anything for the `items`.

Comment: @Ja8zyjits : Yes that did the trick. But suddenly i realize that the list is empty! I would be grateful if you see this code. I used this script to insert menu items : http://pastebin.com/e2XUruJi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need the [all()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all) function at your `items`. You are querying properly but you are not fetching the results.

so your code will be like this

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/')
def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id):
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id=restaurant.id).all()
    output = ''
    for i in items:
        output += i.name
        output += '</br>'
        output += i.price
        output += '</br>'
        output += i.description
        output += '</br>'
        output += '</br>'
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Now it will depend on the entries in your db, if you have any or else it will return an empty `[]`. So if you have the results, you can print and check or loop and render it to your templates.

This should fix your issue

Comment: Yes that did the trick. But suddenly i realize that the list is empty! I would be grateful if you see this code. I used this script to insert menu items : http://pastebin.com/e2XUruJi

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh I shall look into it, but that will be another question, right?
Please accept this if it solves the problem for which you posted initially. :)

Comment: I accepted your answer! If you could now just look into the script... I will ask another question then!

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh that will be the proper way to do it in here. One small advise use `session.commit()` at the end of all the `add` and if possible use a `csv`, that shall be a better way to do it instead of writing all entries.

Comment: I am pursuing an online course from Udacity. They had provided me with this file! That is why I used it. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh also base sqlalchemy is not appropriate for flask, for proper session management use [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/)